# Apache Thrift undefined reference to vtable in Generated Code

Tags: c++, debugging, thrift

I'm using Apache Thrift in a project.  I generated code for the client.  When I attempt to compile I get a set of similar linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `vtable for com::cybersecwise::thrift::ElasticFSServiceClient'
```

I got this same error when trying to implement the constructor using point scope resolution, but I was able to get rid of it by implementing it in the hpp file.  That is, the following code:

```
ElasticFSThriftClient(const string& server, int port) {
  stdcxx::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket(server, port));
  stdcxx::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  stdcxx::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
  ElasticFSServiceClient client(protocol);
}
```

The problem now is I'm instantiating the class, and getting the undefined reference to vtable again.

I am aware that this error is associated when declarations are not defined for virtual functions.  The thing is it seems to compile just fine as long as I don't instantiate the object.

```
ElasticFSThriftClient elasticFsClient("localhost", 9090);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually quite simple.  I forgot to add the generated code files when compiling the project.

Comment: I was about to ask that question.